# Send data from one table to another table

Tags: plsql

I have the following task:

**Task description**

There is table of facts of some services usage by clients:

[image: image1]

USAGES table is stored in schema USAGE_MGMT. It is filled by external application once a month.
It’s necessary to implement Bill Calculation solution for preparation of Bills for clients, by reading of USAGES table and filling the following tables in BILL_CALC schema, to have calculation results detailed in three levels hierarchy:

[image: image2]

Solution shall be implemented in DB stored package(s). It shall allow launching of Bill Calculation process for particular month and year, for single or all client(s). 
Solution shall be applicable for mass calculation process, assuming USAGES table can contain billions of records for different clients and usage dates. Process shall not stop if PRICE column is empty for some usage record, but error shall be logged and calculation process shall be continued for next client.
Assuming USAGE_MGMT and BILL_CALC schemas are in different Oracle DB instances and sys admin rights are granted for both, provide DDL scripts for necessary DB entities creation, including (but not limited to) DB link, Grants, Packages specifications and bodies, Table Indexes etc.

**My question is how to send data from USAGES table to other three tables? Also, why packages are needed? We need three SELECT statements that will become cursors, and one procedure. Am I right?**

EDIT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (p_year        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_month       IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_client_id   IN NUMBER)
IS
    num_of_clients   NUMBER;
    t_client_id      NUMBER;

    CURSOR cur_clients
    IS
        SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_ID
          FROM USAGE_MGMT.USAGES;

    CURSOR cur_bill_total
    IS
        SELECT u.CLIENT_ID
          FROM USAGE_MGMT.USAGES u;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('number of clients' || num_of_clients);

    OPEN cur_clients

    LOOP
        FETCH cur_clients INTO t_client_id;

        EXIT WHEN cur_clients%NOTFOUND;
        --INSERT INTO
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Client:' || t_client_id);
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

**I am interested in how to do INSERT INTO?**

EDIT:

Could someone check the following procedure? It is giving me an error: `Error(44,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (p_year        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_month       IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_client_id   IN NUMBER)
IS
    vIDArray         DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;

    vIDClientArray   DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bill_total (id,
                            client_id,
                            month,
                            year,
                            first_usage_date,
                            last_usage_date,
                            cost)
        SELECT *
          FROM (WITH Myfilter
                     AS (SELECT p_client_id         pClientID,
                                TO_NUMBER (p_month) pMonth,
                                TO_NUMBER (p_year)  pYear,
                                TO_DATE (
                                       LPAD (p_month, 2, '0')
                                    || LPAD (p_year, 4, '0'),
                                    'MMYYYY')
                                    FirstOfMonth
                           FROM DUAL)
                  SELECT usage_mgmt.seq_usages.NEXTVAL,
                         u.client_ID,
                         f.pMonth,
                         f.pYear,
                         MIN (u.DTE),
                         MAX (u.DTE),
                         SUM (u.Price)         -- or SUM(u.Quantity * u.Price)
                    FROM Myfilter f
                         JOIN usage_mgmt.usages u
                             ON (NVL (f.pClientID, u.client_ID) = u.client_ID
                             AND u.DTE >= f.FirstOfMonth
                             AND u.DTE < ADD_MONTHS (f.FirstOfMonth, 1))
                GROUP BY u.client_ID, f.pMonth, f.pYear
                  HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN u.Price IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) =
                             0)
      RETURNING id, client_id
           BULK COLLECT INTO vIDArray, vIDClientArray;
END;
```

EDIT:

What is wrong with this? The problem is in the SUBTOTAL inner loop. It doesn't print all the necessary rows.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_test2

(p_year IN VARCHAR2, p_month IN VARCHAR2, p_client_id IN NUMBER)

IS

--num_of_clients NUMBER;

--t_client_id NUMBER;



f_client_id NUMBER;

f_month VARCHAR2(100);

f_year VARCHAR2(100);

f_cost NUMBER;

f_min_date DATE;

f_max_date DATE;



f2_client_id NUMBER;

f2_unit_of_measure NUMBER;

f2_quantity NUMBER;

f2_cost NUMBER;



/*cursor cur_clients is

select distinct CLIENT_ID

from USAGE_MGMT.USAGES;



cursor cur_bill_total is

select u.CLIENT_ID

from USAGE_MGMT.USAGES u;*/



cursor cur_table1 is

select u.CLIENT_ID,to_char(sysdate, 'MM'), to_char(sysdate, 'YY') , SUM(u.QUANTITY*u.PRICE) AS COST, MIN(u.DTE), MAX(u.DTE)

from USAGES u

where u.CLIENT_ID=p_client_id

and to_char(u.DTE, 'MM')=p_month

and to_char(u.DTE, 'YY')=p_year

GROUP BY CLIENT_ID,to_char(sysdate, 'MM'), to_char(sysdate, 'YY')

;



cursor cur_table1_all is

select CLIENT_ID,to_char(sysdate, 'MM'), to_char(sysdate, 'YY') , SUM(u.QUANTITY*u.PRICE) AS COST, MIN(u.DTE), MAX(u.DTE)

from USAGES u

where

to_char(u.DTE, 'MM')=p_month

and to_char(u.DTE, 'YY')=p_year

GROUP BY CLIENT_ID, to_char(sysdate, 'MM'), to_char(sysdate, 'YY')

;



cursor cur_table2 is

select

u.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, SUM(u.QUANTITY),SUM(u.QUANTITY*u.PRICE) AS COST

from USAGES u

where u.CLIENT_ID=p_client_id

and to_char(u.DTE, 'MM')=p_month

and to_char(u.DTE, 'YY')=p_year

GROUP BY UNIT_OF_MEASURE

;



cursor cur_table2_all is

select

u.CLIENT_ID,u.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, SUM(u.QUANTITY),SUM(u.QUANTITY*u.PRICE) AS COST

from USAGES u

--where u.CLIENT_ID=p_client_id

where to_char(u.DTE, 'MM')=p_month

and to_char(u.DTE, 'YY')=p_year

GROUP BY CLIENT_ID,UNIT_OF_MEASURE

;



cursor cur_table3 is

select



u.TYPE_ID,MIN(u.DTE),MAX(u.DTE),SUM(u.QUANTITY),u.UNIT_OF_MEASURE,u.PRICE,SUM(u.QUANTITY*u.PRICE) AS COST

from USAGES u

where u.TYPE_ID=p_client_id

and to_char(u.DTE, 'MM')=p_month

and to_char(u.DTE, 'YY')=p_year



GROUP BY UNIT_OF_MEASURE,TYPE_ID,PRICE

;





seq_id NUMBER;

seq_id_2 NUMBER;



begin

--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('number of clients'||num_of_clients);

/*open cur_clients;

loop

fetch cur_clients

into t_client_id;

exit when cur_clients%notfound;*/



--INSERT INTO

if(p_client_id=0) then

open cur_table1_all;

else open cur_table1;

end if;



/*if(p_client_id=0) then

open cur_table2_all;

else open cur_table2;

end if;*/



open cur_table2;



loop



if(p_client_id=0) then

fetch cur_table1_all into f_client_id, f_month, f_year, f_cost, f_min_date, f_max_date;

exit when cur_table1_all%notfound;

else

fetch cur_table1 into f_client_id, f_month, f_year, f_cost, f_min_date, f_max_date;

exit when cur_table1%notfound;



end if;





SELECT BILL_CALC.SEQ_BILL_TOTAL.NEXTVAL into seq_id from dual;

INSERT INTO BILL_CALC.BILL_TOTAL (ID, CLIENT_ID, MONTH, YEAR, FIRST_USAGE_DATE, LAST_USAGE_DATE, COST)

VALUES(seq_id, f_client_id, f_month, f_year , f_min_date, f_max_date, f_cost );



loop



/*if(p_client_id=0) then

fetch cur_table2_all into f2_client_id,f2_unit_of_measure,f2_quantity,f2_cost;

exit when cur_table2_all%notfound;*/

--else

fetch cur_table2 into f2_unit_of_measure,f2_quantity,f2_cost;

exit when cur_table2%notfound;

--end if;



if(f2_client_id=f_client_id) then

SELECT BILL_CALC.SEQ_BILL_SUBTOTAL.NEXTVAL into seq_id_2 from dual;

INSERT INTO BILL_CALC.BILL_SUBTOTAL (ID, BILL_TOTAL_ID, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, QUANTITY,COST)

VALUES(seq_id_2, seq_id, f2_unit_of_measure, f2_quantity, f2_cost);

end if;



end loop;





--dbms_output.put_line ('Client:'||t_client_id);

end loop;

if (p_client_id=0) then

close cur_table1_all;

else

close cur_table1;



end if;



/*if (p_client_id=0) then

close cur_table2_all;

else

close cur_table2;



end if;*/



close cur_table2;



commit;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks user11153823.  It is a little unusual for a functional requirement to layout the exact details of implementation like this.  Perhaps there are other solutions than the presented implementation.  Is this homework?  Could you tag it as such, if so?  That would help clarify things.  Thanks

Comment: No, it is not a homework.

Comment: you may use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<YOUR INSERT STATEMENT>';